# Set Use Default on custom option title programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I'm adding and removing custom options programmatically like so:

```php
$product = $this->getProductModel()
    ->setStoreId($taskStore)
    ->load($productId);
$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance();
$optionInstance->setProduct($product);
$optionInstance->setOptions($customOptions);
```

If `$taskStore` is not 0, this adds store-level overrides, which is what I want. However, sometimes I want to only set a store-level override on the titles of dropdown values, not the title of the option itself. If I set the option title to `false`, it still has a blank store-level override:

```php
foreach ($customOptions as &$customOption) {
    $customOption['title'] = false;
}
unset($customOption);
$product = $this->getProductModel()
    ->setStoreId($taskStore)
    ->load($productId);
$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance();
$optionInstance->setProduct($product);
$optionInstance->setOptions($customOptions);
```

**The result:**

[image]

**The goal:**

[image]

How can I set the title of a custom option to use the default global-scope value while still setting store-level overrides on the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By logging `$this->getData()` just prior to `$this->save()` in the `saveOptions()` method of `Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option.php` and then saving the product from the Magento admin page (with Use Default selected on the option title and first value title), I finally figured it out. The logging gave me this result:

```json
{
    "is_delete": "",
    "previous_type": "drop_down",
    "previous_group": "select",
    "id": "9094",
    "option_id": "9094",
    "scope": {
        "title": "1"
    },
    "type": "drop_down",
    "is_require": "1",
    "sort_order": "1",
    "quantity_options_checkbox": "0",
    "values": {
        "18781": {
            "option_type_id": "18781",
            "is_delete": "",
            "scope": {
                "title": "1"
            },
            "price": "0.00",
            "price_type": "fixed",
            "sku": "",
            "sort_order": "1"
        },
        "18782": {
            "option_type_id": "18782",
            "is_delete": "",
            "title": "Large (12x16\")",
            "price": "0.00",
            "price_type": "fixed",
            "sku": "",
            "sort_order": "2"
        }
    },
    "product_id": "6405",
    "store_id": "1"
}
```

Which tells me all I need to do is add a new `scope` key that specifies which fields should be global-scope:

```php
foreach ($customOptions as &$customOption) {
    $customOption['scope'] = ['title' => '1']; // 1 == Global scope
}
unset($customOption);
$product = $this->getProductModel()
    ->setStoreId($taskStore)
    ->load($productId);
$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance();
$optionInstance->setProduct($product);
$optionInstance->setOptions($customOptions);
```

Knowing how weird and complex the custom option tables are in the database, I know why they did it this way, but it was completely unintuitive. I just wish I'd thought of logging the model save earlier.